# Frequency count for each column in pandas dataset using a generalised approach

Tags: pandas

I have  a pandas dataframe with Binary values in the columns as such.

```
Id Label1 Label2 ......

1    0      1  

2    1      1 

3    1      1

4    1      1
```

The output I am looking for is as follows

```
Label1

  3

Label2

  4
```

How do I do this using some form of code that reads each of the columns in the whole panda data-frame and provides the sum for that column. I do know how to do it for one column.

Comment: I do not want it for just a single column, but sorry if I have not made myself clear, how do I do it for each column at the same time. I do know how to do it for a single column.

Comment: You can use a `for` loop.. Try it, share your code, show us where you got stuck, why you got stuck, what error you get, etc. Your desired output also makes no sense (is that a dataframe with 4 rows?).

Comment: No I have 160 rows and 4500+ columns so that is quite a huge matrix, so I just wrote a simple example here to start with. I am reading online now how to do this with a for loop.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51191615/edit) with *all* your requirements, then vote to reopen. If others agree with you, it'll be reopened. An example here should include your *existing* code, not just input + output.

Comment: `for col in df.columns:
    s = df.groupby([col]).size()
    print(s)`

Comment: I have tried the above python code and it seems to do the job! If there is a neater way then please let me know @jpp